# Where are granted permissions stored in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

When a user is granted rights to something in SQL Server using the GRANT function where is it recorded?

Comment: Which version of MSSQL?

Comment: I actually don't have a particular version of SQL in mind for this but just a general inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

In the "Master" database:

```
sys.syslogins
sys.sysusers
sys.sql_logins
```

I think the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES is only a list of what is allowed to be granted, and by whom.

There is a `sys.syspermissions` table, but it's wildly ugly to look at, and I'm not wholly sure what it's storing.

**Edit: It's none of the above. Instead it's the aptly named** `sys.database_permissions` **table.** Now I feel stupid.

Comment: sys.database_permissions looks like it's the one. Thanks. And holy smokes that sys.syspermissions is quite ugly!

Answer (score 2):

Server level permissions are stored in internal tables exposed through the [sys.server_premissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186260.aspx) catalog view.

Database level permissions are stored in internal tables exposed through the [sys.database_permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx) catalog view.

A session can check its permissions by interrogating the built-in [fn_my_permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx) table function.

To verify if a sessions has a specific permission, use the [HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx) function.

Comment: Good stuff. That HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME function should help me track down some other permission information I'm curious about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look first in the master database. Try INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES.